# Count Checkboxes:checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am trying to figure out the simplest method to add up all checked checkboxes. I researched over the past few weeks and the answers don't seem to help or seem very complicated for such a simple task.

I am trying to add up the number of checked checkboxes, in order to compare it to 'criteria'. For example I need to meet 3/3 criteria (therefore I met my criteria once 3 checkboxes are selected).Every time a checkbox is checked, i'd like it to show right away that another criteria point is added.

Can someone help guide me? I felt angular was best for double binding and live update, however I know there’s a key up function for jquery which may do similar. Below was my best shot but didn’t work:

```
<input type=“checkbox” id=“Criteria1”>
<input type=“checkbox” id=“Criteria2”>
<input type=“checkbox” id=“Criteria3”>


<div id="message"></div>

<p><span id="result"></span> / <span id="total"></span></p>
     <!--User sees that its 1/3, or 2/3, or 3/3 as they check off-->

While (checkbox.checked){ <!--Not sure if i should use "for" instead-->
 Var i = i+1 <!--Adds one to result-->
 } else
 Var i = i-1; <!--returns to value before checked-->
}

<script>
Var criteria=“3”;
Var result=“0”;
If (result<criteria){
 document.getElementByID("message") = "Criteria Not yet Met";
} else {
document.getElementByID("message") ="Criteria Met!";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `change` event from the checkboxes to wait for one to be checked (or unchecked).
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

I wrote a quick pen to give an example:
https://codepen.io/Daniel_I_Am/pen/YzzgWma

I put some comments in the codepen, if any of them aren't clear, feel free to add a comment to this post!

Comment: Wow! thank you so much!! This was extremely helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily using jQuery:

```
var criteria="3";
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input:[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
                if($("input:[type=checkbox]:checked").length==criteria)
                    alert("Criteria Met!");
                else
                    alert("Criteria Not yet Met");
            })
        })
```

don't forget to call jQuery before

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use AngularJs:

**App.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.init = function() {
    $scope.criteria = $scope.createData();
    $scope.totalSelected = 0;
    $scope.criteriaMet = '';
  }

  $scope.createData = function() {
    return [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Criteria One',
        'selected': false
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Criteria Two',
        'selected': false
      },
      {
        'id': 3,
        'name': 'Criteria Three',
        'selected': false
      },
    ];
  }


  $scope.updateTotal = function(item) {
      if (item) {
        $scope.totalSelected++;
      }
      else {
        $scope.totalSelected--;
      }

      if($scope.criteria.length == $scope.totalSelected){
        $scope.criteriaMet = 'Criteria Met!'
      }
      else {
        $scope.criteriaMet = 'Criteria Not yet Met'
      }
  }

  $scope.init();

});
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Criteria</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.15"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >
    <form ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in criteria">
          <td>
          <input type="checkbox" 
                 value="{{item.id}}"
                 ng-model="item.selected"
                 ng-change="updateTotal(item.selected)"> &nbsp; {{item.name}}
           </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
       <p>
          {{ criteriaMet}}
       </p>
    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```